# System.InvalidCastException: Can't convert VarChar to Int32 at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal)

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, jwt, visual-studio-2019

I have an API whith a Controller called Token Controller which validates a user and gives a token.

The problem is it was working just fine until now, I didn't change anything so I have no idea what happened. Please help.

Here is the code of my Token controller

```
    public TokenController(IConfiguration configuration, ICrUserInfoService crUserInfoService, IPasswordService passwordService)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _crUserInfoService = crUserInfoService;
        _passwordService = passwordService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authentication(UserLogin login)
    {
        //if it is a valid user 
        var validation = await IsValidUser(login);
        if (validation.Item1)
        {
            var token = GenerateToken(validation.Item2);
            return Ok(new { token });
        }

        return NotFound("Unvalid User");
    }
    private async Task<(bool, CrUserInfo)> IsValidUser(UserLogin login)
    {
        var user = await _crUserInfoService.GetLoginByCredentials(login);
        bool isValid;

        if (user == null)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = _passwordService.Check(user.Password, login.Password);
        }

        return (isValid, user);

    }

    private string GenerateToken(CrUserInfo user)
    {
        //Header
        var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Authentication:SecretKey"]));
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);

        //Claims
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            new Claim("User", user.Displayname),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString()),
        };

        //Payload
        var payload = new JwtPayload
        (
            _configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
            _configuration["Authentication:Audience"],
            claims,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
        );

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

As I said it was working just fine till now and here is the error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Can't convert VarChar to Int32
   at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 223
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 242
   at lambda_method23(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Crijoya.Infrastructure.Repositories.CrUserInfoRepository.GetLoginByCredentials(UserLogin login) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\Api Crijoya\Crijoya.Data\Repositories\CrUserInfoRepository.cs:line 15
   at Crijoya.Core.Services.CrUserInfoService.GetLoginByCredentials(UserLogin userLogin) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\Api Crijoya\Crijoya.Model\Services\CrUserInfoService.cs:line 20
   at Api_Crijoya.Controllers.TokenController.IsValidUser(UserLogin login) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\Api Crijoya\Api Crijoya\Controllers\TokenController.cs:line 51
   at Api_Crijoya.Controllers.TokenController.Authentication(UserLogin login) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\Api Crijoya\Api Crijoya\Controllers\TokenController.cs:line 40
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I am not sure the issue is in the code as I said it was working minutes ago and giving a correct Token. Please help I don't know how to approach this.

**EDIT**:

The repository of my entity CrUserInfo which contains the user and password

```
public CrUserInfoRepository(db_crijoyaContext context) : base(context) { }

        public async Task<CrUserInfo> GetLoginByCredentials(UserLogin login)
        {
            return await _entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == login.User);
        }
```

Here is my entity CrUserInfo

```
public partial class CrUserInfo : BaseEntity
    {
       // public int IdUserInfo { get; set; }
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public string Displayname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public RoleType Role { get; set; }

        public virtual CrUser IdUserNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

My Dto entity

```
public class CrUserInfoDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public string Displayname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public RoleType Role { get; set; }
    }
```

My database

[image]

[image]

Here is the script

```
CREATE TABLE `cr_userInfo` (
  `id_userInfo` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `displayname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_userInfo`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_user` (`id_user`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `cr_userInfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `cr_user` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is what it did before it stopped working

[image]

[image]

ONMODELCREATING CODE:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CrUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                    .HasName("PRIMARY");

                entity.ToTable("cr_user");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.IdCompany, "company");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnType("uint(6) unsigned")
                    .HasColumnName("id_user");

                entity.Property(e => e.Active)
                    .HasColumnType("tinyint(1) unsigned")
                    .HasColumnName("active")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'1'");

                entity.Property(e => e.IdCompany)
                    .HasColumnType("int(6) unsigned")
                    .HasColumnName("id_company");

                entity.Property(e => e.Warehouse)
                    .HasColumnType("int(6)")
                    .HasColumnName("warehouse")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'NULL'");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.IdCompanyNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.CrUsers)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdCompany)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("cr_user_ibfk_1");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<CrUserInfo>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                    .HasName("PRIMARY");

                entity.ToTable("cr_userInfo");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.IdUser, "id_user")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnType("uint(6) unsigned")
                    .HasColumnName("id_userInfo");

                entity.Property(e => e.Displayname)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("displayname");

                entity.Property(e => e.IdUser)
                    .HasColumnType("int(6) unsigned")
                    .HasColumnName("id_user");

                entity.Property(e => e.Password)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("password");

                entity.Property(e => e.Role)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .HasColumnName("role");

                entity.Property(e => e.Username)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("username");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.IdUserNavigation)
                    .WithOne(p => p.CrUserInfo)
                    .HasForeignKey<CrUserInfo>(d => d.IdUser)
                    .HasConstraintName("cr_userInfo_ibfk_1");
            });
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, the issue is in `GetLoginByCredentials` and not in the code that you've shown us. Either way, it seems that a database column you're expecting to hold a number is actually a `varchar` (i.e. a `string` value).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I just posted my method GetLoginByCredentials but as I said it was working minutes ago without changing anything. My database fields are string as well as my code

Comment: Does `CrUserInfo` contain an `int` that isn't a number type on the database side? Perhaps you could provide the definition of `CrUserInfo` and your table's definition.

Comment: `My database fields are string` that's what the error complains about. At least one field isn't a string. Perhaps the ID? Please post the `CrUserInfo` class and the table schema (the `CREATE TABLE` statement)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I added my entity and database but I don't understand how it would stop working suddenly without changing my database or my entity

Comment: I expect it's trying to interpret `role` as an integer. Can you try adding `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]` above `public RoleType Role { get; set; }`?

Comment: What are `BaseEntity` and `RoleType`? Is `RoleType` an enum? Enums are integers with a label, not strings. Have you configured that property to be stored as a string? You can't do that with `Column`, you have to use `HasConversion` in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Perhaps I misunderstood the documentation, but it seemed like you could do it with `Column`. This isn't my area of expertise though, so maybe I'm wrong. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#pre-defined-conversions

Comment: Oops, somehow I always read (and use) the first part of that paragraph. The other possible problem is the `CrUser` entity. Or bad mapping in `OnModelCreating`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos BaseEntity is my generic entity which stores the id and my roletype is an emun class. So how can I use hasconversion? I will try that

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I remembered why I don't use `Column`, ASP.NET Core OData will change its metadata if it sees the `Column` attribute. So I use `OnModelCreating` for any mappings I don't want to affect other libraries

Comment: And: NEVER store passwords in a database. Use salted hash values instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That certainly makes sense.

Comment: @KlausGütter I'm storing hash values on my database

Comment: OP: Please show your `OnModelCreating` code.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I have added my OnModelCreating code. It is autogenerated as I did the Scaffolding

Comment: So I have to thank you all so much, I did the conversion on my OnModelCreating and it is working again now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update your `OnModelCreating` code from this:

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.Role)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(30)
    .HasColumnName("role");
```

To indicate that it should be `string`:

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.Role)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(30)
    .HasColumnName("role")
    .HasConversion<string>();
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#pre-defined-conversions), this should automatically convert between the database `varchar` type and the `RoleType` in C#:

> For example, enum to string conversions are used as an example above, but EF Core will actually do this automatically when the provider type is configured as string using the generic type of `HasConversion`: